# Error when updating entities EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following schema:

[image: Schema image]

How properly to update the entities using EF code first approach? When I try to do it with :

```
this._context.Entry(foundEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
this._context.Entry(foundEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It throws exception and says:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Bets_dbo.Matches_MatchID". The conflict occurred in database "UltraPlay.Betting.Platform", table "dbo.Matches", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is it possible to pass the root object and all the childs to be updated? How properly to do this clean and fast?

Comment: Can you show your entity?

Comment: please share your code and tell where are you getting error

Comment: I suppose, the variable "entity" is detached. Is it right?

Comment: What is `foundEntity`, what is `entity` and what are their values? (To ask just a few obvious questions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *attach* an element with child elements, you need to *attach* all child elements as well, e.g.

```
this._context.Entry(foundEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
this._context.Entry(foundEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

this._context.Entry(entity.ChildElement).State = EntityState.Modified; // <--
```

if it exists already.

Otherwise EF assumes that the child element is new to the model and tries to insert it (again).